# Java Regex Remove Text Between and Including Parenthesis from String

Tags: java, regex

I am programming in Java, and I have a few Strings that look similar to this:

```
"Avg. Price ($/lb)" 
"Average Price ($/kg)"
```

I want to remove the `($/lb)` and `($/kg)` from both Strings and be left with

```
"Avg. Price" 
"Average Price".
```

My code checks whether a String **str** variable matches one of the strings above, and if it does, replaces the text inside including the parentheses with an empty string:

```
    if(str.matches(".*\\(.+?\\)")){

           str = str.replaceFirst("\\(.+?\\)", "");
    }
```

When I change str.matches to str.contains("$/lb"); as a test, the wanted substring is removed which leads me to believe there is something wrong with the if statement. Any help as to what I am doing wrong? Thank you.

**Update**
I changed the if statement to:

```
if(str.contains("(") && str.contains (")"))
```

Maybe not an elegant solution but it seems to work.

Comment: The snippet you've shown works correctly for me.  So the problem is somewhere else in your program.  Maybe you could post your entire program instead of just two lines?

Comment: Program works fine for me as well. I ran the following snippet: `String str = "Hi ($/lb)"; System.out.println("\"" + str + "\""); if (str.matches(".* \\(.+?\\)")) {
 str = str.replaceFirst(" \\(.+?\\)", ""); } System.out.println("\"" + str + "\"");` and got the expected `"Hi ($/lb)" "Hi"`.

Comment: You can use the `find()` method in `java.util.regex.Matcher` to find non-exhaustive matches, but you really don't need to.  `replaceFirst()` and `replaceAll()` handle all the searching as well as the replacing.  If they don't find any matches, they return the original string unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

str.matches has always been problematic for me. I think it implies a '^' and '$' surrounding the regex you pass it.

Since you just care about replacing any occurrence of the string in question - try the following:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\s+\\(\\$\\/(lb|kg)\\)", "");
```

There is an [online regex testing tool](https://regex101.com/) that you can also try out to see how your expression works out.

**EDIT** With regard to your comment, the expression could be altered to just:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\s+\\([^)]+\\)$", "");
```

This would mean, find any section of content starting with one or more white-space characters, followed by a literal '(', then look for any sequence of non-')' characters, followed by a literal ')' at the end of the line.

Is that more in-line with your expectation?

Additionally, heed the comment with regard to 'matches()' vs 'find()' that is very much so what is impacting operation here for you.

Comment: I appreciate the help. The two strings above were just an example. I have different strings other than "Avg. Price ($/lb)" and "Average Price ($/kg)". Too many to list so I don't think your solution will work.

Comment: More precisely, it acts like your regex was really `"\\A(?: + yourRegex + ")\\z"`.  For non-exhaustive matches you have to use `java.util.regex.Matcher.find()`.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike most other popular application languages, the [`matches()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-) method in java only returns `true` if the regex matches the *whole* string (not *part* of the string like in perl, ruby, php, javascript etc).

The regex to match bracketed input, including any leading spaces, is:

```
" *\\(.*?\\)"
```

and the code to use this to remove matches is:

```
str = str.replaceAll(" *\\(.+?\\)", "");
```

---

Here's some test code:

```
String str = "foo (stuff) bar(whatever)";
str = str.replaceAll(" *\\(.+?\\)", "");
System.out.println(str);
```

Output:

```
"foo bar"
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is working fine.

```
    String str = "Avg. Price ($/lb) Average Price ($/kg)";

    if (str.matches(".*\\(.+?\\)")) {
        str = str.replaceFirst("\\(.+?\\)", "");
    }
    System.out.println("str: "+str);
```

This will print **Avg. Price  Average Price** which is what you need.

Note: I changed **replaceFirst** with **replaceAll** here.

Answer (score 0):

String first = "^(\\w+\\.\\s\\w+)";

This would print out Avg. Price

String second="(\\w\\s\\w)";

This would print out Average Price

hope this simple answer helps